# Javascript elements within frame loading from an external source (Chrome Content Script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, frames

Ok, so in the following example how would I go about changing the text of the h2 ? I have tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to work. I have tried so many things that it would be pointless to post them all here, so I am hoping someone can just post how. The frame is being loaded from an external url and I am/will be using JQuery so feel free to use anything from it. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="http://loadingfrom.com/">
        <html>
             <head>...</head>
             <body>
                 <div><h2 id="idOfH2">Hello</h2></div>
                 <div></div>
                 <div></div>
                 <div></div>
             </body>
        </html>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the id attribute to your H2 tag like this:

```
<h2 id="idOfH2">Hello</h2>
```

----- Edit -----

Make sure you have:

```
"all_frames": true
```

set in the content_scripts section of the manifest.json file.

Comment: that was a typo *fixed, and it is not my page its external so i have to work with what i have.

Comment: adding all_frames doesn't change anything. Currently I am trying "alert($("idOfH2").textContent);" and the alert shows "object [Object]" or "alert($("#idOfH2").textContent);" shows "undefined"

Comment: I hope you mean that `alert($("idOfH2").textContent)` shows `undefined` and `alert($("#idOfH2").textContent)` shows `object [Object]`, otherwise you have some serious problems. Have you tried inspecting/debugging to see what the object actually is/has?

Comment: What was the result? You shouldn't use forums like this if you aren't going to be courteous and accept people's answers or at least comment on your solutions/workarounds. I'm judging from the username this person probably won't be back...